# SQL error when loading empty laravel blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is an app that previous developers have worked on and might have something hidden I'm not aware of.

There's a simple route that uses no middleware and loads a view.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return view('media');
}
```

This returns

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
```

This **happens even if media.blade.php is empty** and **stops happen if I comment out** `return view('media')`.

This is media.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', __('Files and Links'))

@section('content')
    <media :privacy="{{ $privacy }}"></media>
@endsection
```

Even when I empty the file it's the same.

Where can queries be happening if that's all there is?

Comment: can you try php artisan `opt:clear` which clears all the cache

Comment: post your `media.blade.php` file code here

Comment: Check how many files available in your routes folder

Comment: @Manojkiran.A is this how the command is spelled? Artisan tells me there's no `opt` namespace.

@SalmanZafar in a second! :)

@Rishi you mean what other than web? Channels, console and api.

Comment: @Maximilian Berbechelov Laravel version pls

Comment: @Manojkiran.A 5.6.39

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Nope, still returns the error when the view is loaded. Nothing else in views or their loading seems cached.

Comment: Try to restart your server. if apache `sudo service apache2 restart`.